# Linux: How to check if multiple batch files have completed execution or not

Tags: linux, batch-processing

I have scheduled a dozen batch files (each containing a dozen commands) to run in parallel through crontab. Now I want to run another commmand, but only after all the batches have completed execution. How do I do this?

Comment: batch files are used in windows its bash files instead

Comment: Have a good return/exit status at the end of each bash file(commands in it) and just look for those status before going to next...
ask for an example if required

Comment: Jord, please provide example.

Comment: What about using a trap and a counter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute Shell script after other script got executed successfully](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902371/execute-shell-script-after-other-script-got-executed-successfully)

Answer (score 0):

[Execute Shell script after other script got executed successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902371/execute-shell-script-after-other-script-got-executed-successfully)

The above post answers you with example, you can no the exit status of any command execution of shell script with $? and then call another script.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker